# then and catch error while deploying the node js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run a sample code from Github to insert the data in fire store database but I am getting an error.

Here is the error:

```
 21:1   error    Expected catch() or return promise/catch-or-return
 21:35  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return a value  or  throw
```

Here  is the code where I am getting the error:

```
// getting data
db.collection('cafes').get().then((snapshot) => {  //----line 21 
snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
renderCafe(doc);

})
});
```

Comment: Those are lint warnings indicating that your code is violating some best practices, and may be incorrect. You've probably taken your code out of context (does this involve Cloud Functions?) so it's impossible to say if what you're doing is actually correct or not.  Have you tried googling those messages to get more details on the advice you've been given?

Answer (score 0):

Those look like lint warnings, not actual JS errors unless you're running this in some non-standard environment.

The first one appears to be telling you that you have no `.catch()` to handle errors from your db `.get()`.  That's good advice.  You must handle errors.

The second one appears to be wrong.  There's no rule that you have to return a value from a `.then()`.  If it's the end of the chain and you're done with the processing, there's no reason to return anything.  You can probably make the second warning go away by putting a `return 0` after `renderCafe(doc)`, though personally I'd either stop using a tool that gives such bad advice or configure it not to warn on this issue because it's wrong and adding dummy, non-functional code just to make some tool be happy is not something I recommend.